# how to run many maven goals from eclipse in one click

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

i want to know, if  it's possible to run many `maven`  `goals` from `eclipse` at the same time ,in other way in one click.
for example i have 3 project project1 ,project2 ,project3.
i want for example to clean them all ,and install project1 and project2 then project3 and deploy the 3 projects (in one click) .

it's possible to do such a thing ?

notice : Maven Integration Plugin for Eclipse  is already installed.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run goals for multiple projects using m2e. I suggest the following:

1. If projects are related, bundle them into a parent project and run the deploy goal on the parent project. You will need to tweak the goals that need to run as part of the deploy phase
2. Use an assembly project that uses artifacts from these 3 projects and creates required assemblies and does the deployment
3. Write a script (batch or shell) which executes goals for these projects one after the other. This can be run from eclipse as an external command